# PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>, Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, ienumerable

I'm trying to filter out entities from a `principalcollection` using what I think is called lambda expressions.

I cant get this to work, I get no results.
`user.GetGroups()` returns all the groups where user is member, but `user.GetGroups().Where(....)` does not return anything.

Lets say that userprincipal user = Administrator
Lets say MyFilterString = "Exchange"
Lets say that Administrator is member of the following groups:

```
Exchange Domain Servers
Exchange Services
Administrators
Enterprise Admins
```

Domain Admins
   Schema Admins

```
UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(MyActiveDirectoryContext);
..
..
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> memberOfGroups = user.GetGroups().Where(g => g.SamAccountName.Contains(MyFilterString) == true) as PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>;
```

What I expect is that memberOfGroups should now contain 2 groups:

```
Exchange Domain Servers
Exchange Services
```

But it ends up empty, zip zero, nada.
A little help is very much appreciated.

Simon O. Olsen

Answer (score 2):

If `.Where` is the standard `Enumerable.Where`, then it isn't going to ever return a `PrincipalSearchResult`; so `as` will return `null` every time. Consider using `.ToList()` :

```
var memberOfGroups = user.GetGroups()
      .Where(g => g.SamAccountName.Contains(MyFilterString)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use **IndexOf()** and not **Contains()** like this:

```
PrincipalSearchResult memberOfGroups = user.GetGroups().Where(g => >g.SamAccountName.IndexOf(MyFilterString) > -1) as PrincipalSearchResult;
```

you may want to reformulate your question to be more clearer!